# JavaScript Animation flickers intensely when part of the image is out of the window on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, flicker

If you have an iOS device, you can take a look at the problem here: [removed link]

I have a couple sets of images on this page I'm animating with a custom animation engine. It relies on setTimeout() at the end of its run to decide how long to wait before the next frame so users can adjust the animation speed on the fly. It works great on Desktop but on iOS as soon as any part of the image is out of the window: it flickers like crazy. I tried replacing setTimeout() with requestAnimationFrame() and instead of flickering, the animation just goes blank. I can live with that, but then I lose the ability to adjust the frame rate and the animations look whacky at that speed.

It also certainly has something to do with my hacky workaround to get the page sized correctly for mobile. The main HTML doc is put into an iFrame which is scaled down and then given extra width/height to fill the page. It seems like in the scaling process the phone is not able to accurately keep track of the boundary of the window anymore.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" and other fixes for animation flicker found on here, but none of them have made a dent in the problem.

Comment: If anyone finds this in the future I ended up just checking for partial visibility of the animation frame and killing the animation unless the entire thing is visible. Also removed my link in the post for privacy